# With a shower, should the edge where the wall meets the floor be caulked, or is grout okay?

Tags: shower, caulking, grout

Some of the shower tiles have come loose in my shower and need repair (specifically the ones at the base of the wall).  There's no 'tub' per-se, the whole thing is tiled, and it looks like whoever installed it used grout for the edge where the wall meets the floor.  Assuming everything else goes well... is it better to caulk the bottom edge?  Or is it okay to just use grout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm just a motivated DIY guy, but when I learned tiling I was told to use silicone caulking wherever tile changes directions.  So, inside corners, meeting the floor, etc.

Comment: Your biggest problem will probably be mould, so silicone is better than grout. There is a new white silicone sealant (in Australia, but probably available elsewhere) which sets fast and is mould resistant for 5 years.

Answer (score 6):

Every place I've seen tiled by professionals they do just as Ed Swindelles said, caulk wherever the tiles change direction, as that is where you may have some movement, even if it is only slight. Tiling at home I've tried both grout and caulk and can tell you I wouldn't grout a corner again.