# Should I use caulk or grout between the edge of a tiled bathroom floor and the walls?

Tags: bathroom, caulking, grout, remodeling, tiling

I just tiled my bathroom floor. What should I put between the tiles and the walls, silicone or grout?

Comment: Dup? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/with-a-shower-should-the-edge-where-the-wall-meets-the-floor-be-caulked-or-is?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Use anti-bacterial water sealed silicone. The reasons being that if you use grout then expansion in the tiles can cause the grout to crack along that tile line. Also caulk will get very grubby quickly. Silicone allows expansion and doesn't get grubby like caulk

Comment: I feel there is some ambiguity in the word caulk. You can buy silicone that isn't labeled as caulk - typically labeled silicone sealant - but you can also buy 100% silicone caulk. I don't know if marketing is using the wrong name or if caulk can be generic. Either way the silicone should be in the same isle as caulking, liquid nails, typically in the paint section and is typically available in a small squeeze tube or one that requires a caulking gun just like "caulk"

Comment: a quick point, the tiles do not expand rather the surface they are mounted on has some movement.  This slight movement is enough to cause the grout the crack. Using silicone caulk will be more resilient to this movement.