# Sink is coming off the wall (visible separation). What material do I need to "glue" it back?

Tags: walls, sink, adhesive

As you can see in the picture, my sink is "tilting", or coming off the wall.

[image: Sink wall come off]

It is still in place but if pressure were to be applied, it would fall down completely I reckon.

I can push it towards to wall, it sits back but naturally comes off again.

- What kind of gel, sealant etc. or such material I can buy and apply to glue it up there again?

I'm hoping something exists that is not cement that I'd need to prepare.

Comment: How is it attached to the wall? There must be bolts to the wall or legs to the floor or something, not just glue or chalk. Have you checked whatever mechanical fasteners are there?

Comment: The caulk pulling away is a symptom, and not the problem. Your answer is not going to be any type of glue or something like that.  The answer will be screws, bolts other mechanical fastener.

Comment: Once the mechanical fasteners are used and the sink is pulled back up, what should be used to cover that hole / separation line?

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not going to be as simple as "tighten up the bolts" - mysteriously unscrewing themselves is a low likelihood .vs. "there's some deterioration in the wall where they attach" which will need to be addressed. Or "Someone sat on the sink and stressed them/the wood they were attached to." So, the sink probably needs to come off to effect a lasting repair, unless you have a child that has discovered tools and unscrewing things who's running around the house unscrewing things at random (don't laugh too hard if you have one that could still reach that stage, or the laugh may be on you.) Sink bolts are inconvenient enough that it's probably not that, though.

Once reattached, caulking is the typical material for sealing up the joint line - look for "kitchen and bath caulk" - it's got anti-mold/mildew additives. Exactly what type (material) of caulk is a matter of opinion (which quickly goes off-topic as being a matter of opinion.)

**Edit:** Knowing now that the sink was stressed, the first step will be to see what you can find for fasteners - many sinks are mounted via a "bracket" (as @comintern notes) which may not even be visible until the sink is lifted off of it. If you do look under and see bolts or nuts, try tightening them, and (if that works, rather than they just spin in the wall) then give it a week or so to see if the sink stays put before deciding you're done.

Comment: Beat me to it - the other possibility is that the hanger bracket got bent, but that still leads to the same solution.

Comment: Silicone! -[Discussion](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/25404/should-i-use-caulk-or-grout-between-the-edge-of-a-tiled-bathroom-floor-and-the-w/25409#25409).

Comment: @Mazura you just had to start. In a flying fickle finger of fate move, this question shows up a few minutes later... http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62566/silicon-caulk-for-shower-and-tub I'm going to grab my 11 foot pole and stay out of the resulting opinion-fests.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Now I know how Tester feels about garage wire Q's.

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for answering and explaining the issue. Yes indeed somebody did put pressure on the sink causing this. How can I estimate if it can be fixed by tightening the screws and bolts and stuff or the sink must be taken off and re-installed completely? Thanks again for your help.