# Filling big horizontal gaps in bathroom tile

Tags: bathroom, ceramic-tile, gap

This is one of our first DIY projects, thank you in advance for your help!

We removed an old baseboard of the heating system in the bathroom and were left with a horizontal gap in the tiles. As you can see, the gap between the tiles and the drywood gets up to about 1 3/4" at its widest point.

We heard about grout, epoxy grout, acrylic grout, silicone and other options.

Which one should be best for this case?

[image: Picture with ruler]
[image: Another angle]

Comment: That gap is much to large for grout or caulking. The baseboard trim was the best solution for the improperly installed tile.

Comment: Why do a half-way job? Remove a tile (e.g. slow prying), take it to a store that sells tile, get some matching pieces and a tile-cutter, and do it right. If you plan on keeping the house, you'll live with sloppy work for years, and if you plan to sell, it would reduce the value.

Comment: @AlaskaMan thank you, I forgot to mention that the (ugly) baseboard was of an old heating system which we no longer use. That's why we removed it.

Comment: I agree with @AlaskaMan, that gap needs to be filled with a baseboard molding.

Comment: Fat base (3/4") and a big quarter round will probably make that disappear. Grout the last 1/4" at the wide end.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate what type of grout would you use?

Comment: Same as what's on the floor, ideally. You might need to borrow one of the color keys from  a tile shop, as it's really hard to match at the store with a scrap of existing.

Answer (score 1):

Grey, sanded. 'black' is easy: #60 *charcoal*.

I'd grout it first though. I've had luck with a grout line that wide, and it was a wood-to-tile threshold nonetheless. A 1/2"-plus deep and ~2" wide? I'd go for it; that will seal the gap better too. Then base and quarter round.

I'm an all-or-nothing type of guy, but that's way too much *all* to get excited about what will end up being a slightly too wide grout line along the trim, of an otherwise serviceable tile job. - When you gut the bathroom though....

Comment: *coved base shoe tile* is another option. Just don't use that roll-of-plastic garbage.

Comment: [What is best caulk for a 3/8“ wide X 1” deep gap between a shower floor and wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61863/what-is-best-caulk-for-a-3-8-wide-x-1-deep-gap-between-a-shower-floor-and-wall) - "I'd grout it. Then when the grout fails [along the tile, I'd grout that crack] again." -"by then it's all pretty well settled and a touch-up grouting usually lasts much longer. "